# How to cancel a chat transfer that is queued?

Tags: chat, omnichannel, einstein-chatbot

We have an implementation that uses Omni Channel, Chat & a bot.  Our Chat Button allows Queueing.

In certain scenarios, the bot transfers the request to a Queue that allows queueing.  When it does, the user is shown their Queue order & waits for an agent to become available. While the user is waiting, no user input is allowed.

My question is: is possible to allow the user to stop waiting without ending the chat?

The reason I ask is because I'd like the user to be able to stop waiting & create a Case for them instead (if they choose to stop waiting).

Answer (score 0):

You can build a flow that shows the [estimated wait time](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.live_agent_rest.meta/live_agent_rest/live_agent_rest_estimated_wait_time.htm) before the chat is transferred and offer the option to create a case instead of waiting.

You could also choose to not create a case upon transfer, and only use the Chat Transcript for the transfer. Once the agent accepts the Chat, you can then create a case (use some process automation). The only issue you might have is that the agent might not see the case directly when chatting with the customer.

@Arvid Bux has documented [here](http://sfdc.co/BotAgentTransfer-WaitTime-EXT) on how to 'Calculate Wait Time for Bot to Agent Transfer' that should help you get started.